# GD in Zend Framework - code works in pure php, but in Zend it doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, gd

I have a problem with creating watermark in Zend Framework action.
I have following code, which works perfectly in pure php.
But when i put this in zend action, it doesn't work and I have a message, that image is not displayed, because it has errors...
How can I convert this code to work in Zend Framework?

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('/home/rukia/csigallery/img/qrcode.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('/home/rukia/csigallery/img/kartka.jpg');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: What are the errors? you can see them in your error.log for PHP.

Comment: Image corrupt or truncated: <- this displayes in firebug, when I comment out the header line. And when the header line is commented in my screen in firefox I have something like this: �PNG  IHDR�R�HQ IDATx��y�$�U�yι�FDFf�̷֦�K��.K��I���4/�l�⍶=ӆ�0и����{���^�}�eK��͒jUm�zk��"�.��Y�ʕ�^镪J����x����ȓ���""��r�(�?L�6"r�ӿ/�xj7����v����c��Z�����Y���y���+��s ����`�8��p��~[�8���g%DHtN�.)))yڠ�uJJJJ.T��1�C��%%%%���KJJJ��-)))9CA�4�%%%%O�Ҍ����<)�` and this is for many lines.

Comment: Seems like it's creating the image correctly, is there some other data that might be outputting, like a space or something that will corrupt?

Comment: Have you disabled the layout/view when using it in ZF? Scroll down past the binary data in the browser output to see if there is any HTML code below it. If not, post your ZF version of this code as well.

Comment: Thank You very much, I didn't disable layout, now everything is working as expected :) Sorry, for wasting Your Time in such trivial matter :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Tim Fountain is correct .

Did you disabled your layout and view render ?

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

imagepng($im);
```

Will Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file . In this case browser .